# Current_Timestamp in Trigger with Statement Based Replication

Tags: mysql, timestamp, database-trigger, database-cluster

We currently use a trigger on our MySQL database that sets a "last-modified" timestamp to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. It is called on update.

We also need to use statement based reproduction for the cluster.

Is there a way to modify the trigger so that the propagated `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is identical on every cluster instance?

Currently the statement based reproduction calls the statement for every cluster instance, resulting in slightly different timestamps.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and database triggers are **highly** vendor specific. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Perhaps <sql-server>?

Comment: We use a Mysql Database. I thought since a trigger is implemented by all sql dbs, this information would be enough, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must switch to mixed binlog format to save inside the binlog not only the statement but also the data for non deterministic writes.

You can do that without service disruption with:

```
SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'MIXED';
```

On the master server generating the binlog.